# Capture hotkey in browsers

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, cross-browser

I'm doing SWF application which will run in browser.
And I want to capture `CTRL+F` key pressing event when Flex application is in focus.

In Firefox it works fine but in Opera and Safari browser captures event prior to Flex application and Find Dialog pop-ups.

Is there any way for flex application to capture `CTRL+F` event prior browser?

Answer (score 2):

I asked this [same question recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713447/javascript-global-keyboard-handling-not-hearing-a-z-keys) and have been playing around with it.

I came up with this gist on github:

[Browser KeyboardEvent Hijacking with Javascript and Flex](http://gist.github.com/280019)

CTRL-F works!

Check out the javascript in there.  Basically, with Safari, you can only hear the meta keys (ctrl/alt/shift, etc.); it won't allow javascript to hear A-Z events if Flash is running for some reason.  So I just listen for the meta keys in javascript, and then call `window.focus()` in javascript.  That sets focus to the browser, making it so you can hijack browser keyboard events!.  Then I listen for the A-Z events or whatever, and pass those to Flex.

The next step is to just restore focus in your Flex app to wherever it was before that, which should be easy.

Cheers,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add javascript to your html containing the swf that would block it. It sounds like those browsers process events in a different order so I doubt there would be anything you can do from within the flash player that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Where e is a keyboard event:

```
if(e.commandKey || e.ctrlKey){

    switch(e.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.N:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```